# Displaying each product detail in an online shop

Tags: php, jquery, html, e-commerce, shopping-cart

i'm new to php/html5 etc and i want to create a simple ecommerce site.
I want to put button that will show the more detailed information of the product. My question is, if the button redirects the user to product page does this means i have to make a page for each products?. So, if i have 100 products i have to rewrite 100 page?, Is there a better approach to solve this? Sorry if this is a silly question. thank you

i'll just put random code here because the damned restriction

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("shop-config.php");
include("header.php");
?>
```

Comment: If you want to code a ecommerce site, I'd recommend you to look up for some opensource ones, like woocommerce, magento, opencart, prestashop, etc.

Comment: No, you create a template that will hold a products information, request that information from the database and display that information in the template. You may want to start with http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

Comment: I see, how cannot think of this. thanks and that website seems handy too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to store the products as well as their description in a database, then have one page where you can request that information. I recommend looking into MySQL because it works natively with PHP and it's very easy to use. Once you get the basic queries down and an understanding of SQL, it shouldn't be a problem. :)

(I know this isn't much of an answer, but I don't have my computer on me now and for some reason I can't leave a comment because of my reputation. I guess it's better for new users to spam pseudo-answers than comment xD)